# How to add current user as author to blog using Express and Mongodb

Tags: express, mongoose, jwt, objectid

I am working on a basic Blog site using Express, MongoDB and using JWT for authentication. On valid authentication I am attaching the current user ID to the req object.

I am adding the current User ID as the author of the Blog.

Here're the Blog and User models

```
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {type: String, required: true},
   body: {type: String, required: true},
   author : {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "UserSchema"}
  })
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogSchema);


const UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {type: String, required: true},
   email: {type: String, required: true},
   blogs : [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "BlogSchema"}]
 })
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", UserSchema);
```

I am adding the current user that I am getting from the JWT validation and adding it to the Blog Model instance. This works but **the blog ids are not getting added to the User's blog array**

How to get around it? Please help

Comment: Can you post your response you're getting?

Comment: hey, i actually solved it myself. all i did was after pushing the new blog to the user's blogs[ ] i used user.save()